# arbitrary precision linear algebra c/c++ library with complex numbers

Tags: c++, c, linear-algebra, arbitrary-precision

I'm doing a research involving linear differential equations with complex coefficients in 4-dimensional phase space. To be able to check some hypothesis about the root of the solutions, I need to be able to solve these equations numerically with arbitrary precision. I used to use `mpmath` Python module, but it works slowsly, so I prefer to rewrite my program in C/C++ to achieve maximum perfomance. So I have a question:

Are there any C/C++ linear algebra library exists which support both arbitrary precision arithmetic and complex numbers? I need some basic functionality like dot-products and so on. (Actually, I need matrix exponential too, but I can implement it by myself if necessary).

I tried to use `Eigen` with `MPFR C++`, but failed due to the fact that it doesn't support complex numbers (and construction like `complex <mpreal>` doesn't work as it assumes that the base type is a standard float).

Comment: You could use Eigen with MPFR.

Comment: Question edited to satisfy the guidelines. @Cornstalks, unfortunately, Eigen+MPFR doesn't support complex number now (at least I didn't found how to make it work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it seems that [zkcm](http://sourceforge.net/p/zkcm/home/Home/) did what I want. I'm not sure if it is good from performance viewpoint (didn't do any benchmarks), but at least it works and provides all necessary features.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [uBLAS from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. It seem to be possible to do it, but need to upgrade a lot of stuff on my system (should be using rather modern gcc at least).

Answer (score 1):

Try using an arbitrary precision number library (e.g GMP http://gmplib.org/) with a linear algebra math library that supports complex numbers (e.g. Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't work. At least I didn't manage to do it with MPFR C++ and do not know about different ways to do arbitrary precision with Eigen.

Comment: It should work with the unsupported module http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__MPRealSupport__Module.html

Comment: I tried it (and even contacted the author of MPFR C++), it doesn't support complex numbers yet, only real (note `mpreal` type in the example code). Anyway, thanks.